# Maximum Height for U-Tube (fluids)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

[image: Siphon]

Could someone provide an intuitive explanation for part b of the question and it’s general solution. I’ve tried equating pressures at two points and thought when $h=L$ but I’ve been told I’m wrong - I don’t know why.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example **type** questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/75633) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/75633). You might want to consider posting on [some other Physics website](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/391/75633), such as the [PhysicsForums](https://www.physicsforums.com/forums/homework-and-coursework-questions.152/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A siphon works because the pressures at the two ends of the pipe are different.

[image: Siphon]

The pressure due to a column of water of height $x$ is:

$$ P = \rho_w g x $$

So in this case the pressure on the left side is $\rho_w g h$, the pressure on the right side is $\rho_w g L = \rho_w g (h + d)$, and the pressure difference is:

$$ \Delta P = \rho_w g (h + d) - \rho_w g h = \rho_w g d \tag{1} $$

And as long as $\Delta P \gt 0$ the water will flow. Note that the height $h$ does not appear in equation (1) so it doesn't matter what the value of $h$ is.

However there is a limit on $h$ because the pressure at the top of the siphon is:

$$ P_\text{top} = P_\text{atm} - \rho_w gh $$

and if this pressure falls to below the vapour pressure of the water in the pipe the water will boil and the top of the siphon will fill with water vapour. This will prevent the water from flowing.

Comment: But since the tube is open on the right side, isn’t the atmospheric pressure pushing on the water up on the right side. Hence, that atmospheric pressure cancels out with the atmospheric pressure pushing the water up on the left side? So why can you say the pressure at the top of the siphon equals atmospheric pressure minus the weight of the water.

Comment: @ShayanHemmati: the atmospheric pressure is pushing up on the water on the left hand side of the siphon as well

Comment: But don’t the atmospheric pressures cancel out? Just like they did when we calculated the velocity is part a of the question?

Comment: Yes, the atmospheric pressure does cancel out on the two sides of the tube, so the pressure difference is simply $\rho_w g d$. Note that $d$ is measured from the top of the water in the beaker on the left. I've drawn the tube ending at the surface, but if the end of the tube were below the surface you would measure $d$ from the surface not from the end of the tube.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you with this, but I think I almost got it. Just one last inquiry, since the atmospheric pressures do indeed cancel out, when we are determining when the siphon stops working, why can you simply say the pressure at the top of the siphon equals the atmospheric pressure minus the weight of the water? Didn’t the atmospheric pressure get canceled out? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: The first sentence of this answer should be edited by adding the word "hydrostatic" before "pressure".  IMHO...